# Postgres table growing greatly for no reason

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my postgres database that should be no more that 100,000,000 (actually, about 3.5 million rows at about 20 bytes per row).  My problem is that it is growing to over 15gig in size withon a day or two, and just staying there.  I'm trying to figure out why.

Here is the basic code that loads that table:

```
for x in (

    select
        om_order_id,
        om_order_line_id,
        order_line,
        sublineno
    from
    (
    select
        om_order_id,
        om_order_line_id,
        substring(om_order_line_id, 1, instr(om_order_line_id, '-') -1 )::integer order_line,
        substring(om_order_line_id, instr(om_order_line_id, '-') + 1, 5)::integer sublineno
    from oms.dw_order_lines
    where om_inserted_on >= p_as_of_date
    except
    select
        om_order_id,
        om_order_line_id,
        substring(om_order_line_id, 1, instr(om_order_line_id, '-') -1 )::integer order_line,
        substring(om_order_line_id, instr(om_order_line_id, '-') + 1, 5)::integer sublineno
    from oms.es_order_line_assignments
    ) s
    order by om_order_id, sublineno, order_line

) loop


cnt := cnt + 1;
icnt := x.order_line;

loop
    begin
        insert into oms.es_order_line_assignments(om_order_id, om_order_line_id, line_number)
        values(x.om_order_id, x.om_order_line_id, icnt);
        exit;
    exception when others then
        icnt := icnt + 1;
    end;
end loop;


end loop;
```

This code runs at least once every two hours, and it used to be more.

I don't see anything in here that would cause the space increase.  I'm not actually deleted or updating any rows.  Just inserting one row at a time.

FWIW, now that I'm looking at the code I can see some changes that I can make.  First, the oms.dw_order_lines table is a link to another database, but ( don't need to run it that way anymore.  Second, I am running this code inbetween two different pieces of code, and I see that I can actually  run it first, which means that, Third, I have recently put that code into a large block of code that runs a bunch of smaller functions in order in one transaction, and I since I see that I can run this one first I can actually take it out of that block of code completely.  I will try to do these things, but I am still interested in what other people think.

Thanks,  --sw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the truth:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
\x
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('oms.es_order_line_assignments');
```

This will tell you how many percent of the table are user data, dead (deleted or updated) rows and empty space.  The required action depends on the outcome.

Comment: That is great.  Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, I went into the code and seemed to have figured out what was causing this, although I still don't understand why, so this might not reflect what was going on.  But I will use it in other circumstances.